# Binomial Distribution Question - probability summations

Tags: probability, statistics

> Pi Dumbo is not very bright, but he makes up for it by playing video games all day.  He sits for a 20-question multiple choice examination, each question having five possible answers.  He fills in the answers on the ubble sheet randomly without bothering to read the questions.  Let Y denote the number of questions that Pi Dumbo answers correctly.  Find $\Pr[Y>2]$.

I calculate the probability distribution:  $\Pr[Y=y]=\binom{20}{y} \cdot 0.2^y \cdot 0.8^{20-y}$

To solve the question, I thought I would do the following:

$\Pr[Y>2] = 1 - \Pr[Y \le 2] = 1- \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2}\Pr[y_i]\tag{1}$.

I get the wrong answer doing this.  Apparently, the upper limit on the summation for equation (1) should be 1.  But this doesn't make sense to me according to the 3 laws of probability.  Is there a typo in my book?

I did another question a similar way and got the right answer:

> Kobe Bryant is an eighty percent free-thrower shooter.  In a game against the Portland Trailbrazers, Kobe went to the foul line twelve times.  Let $M$ denote the number of free-throws that Kobe makes.  Assume his shots are independent. Calculate:
>
> (a) the probability distribution,
>
> (b)  $E[M]$
>
> (c)  $Var[M]$
>
> (d)  **What is the probability that Kobe misses more than two shots?**

$\Pr[M=m]=\binom{12}{m} \cdot 0.8^m \cdot 0.2^{12-m}$

$E[M] = 12*0.8=9.6$

$Var[M]=12*0.8*0.2=1.92$

(d) $\Pr[12-M>2]=\Pr[M<10]=1-\Pr[M \ge 10]=0.4417$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it says $\gt 2$ then your procedure is correct. Note that we do have to take $0$ into account, people often forget it.